# Let $x_{1},...,x_{n}\in\mathbb{Z}_{\leq1}$ with sum $1$. There is a circulant permutation s.t $\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{\pi(i)}\leq0 \forall k\leq n-1$.

Tags: combinatorics, integers

Let $x_{1},...,x_{n}$ be integers such that $x_{i}\leq1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=1$. I want to show there exists a **circulant** permutation $\pi$ of ${1,...,n}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{\pi(i)}\leq0$ for all $k\leq n-1$. I tried induction but had problem with the induction step.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: This follows from Raney's lemma, i.e., the cycle lemma.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland I'm not familiar with that result I'm afraid. Could you provide a reference please? Preferably one with a proof of the lemma. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an answer with some references. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n\rangle $ be a sequence of  integers $\leq 1$,
and put $s_0=0$ and $s_j=\sum_{i=1}^j x_i$ for $1\leq j\leq n$.
We consider the path $(j,s_j)$ as $j$ runs from 0 to $n$.

A *rotation* is the path formed using
a rotated sequence of increments $$\langle x_r,x_{r+1},\dots,x_n,x_1,\dots,x_{r-1}\rangle.$$

**Cycle lemma.**  If $s_n>0$, then there are exactly $s_n$ rotations whose
partial sums are strictly positive.

**Corollary.** If $s_n>0$,  then there are exactly $s_n$ rotations
 so that $s_j<s_n$ for $0\leq j<n$.

*Proof:* Apply the cycle lemma to the reversed sequence
$$x^{\rm rev}=\langle x_n,x_{n-1},\dots,x_1\rangle.$$
We have
$s_n-s_j=s^{\rm rev}_{n-j},\quad 0\leq j<n.$

**Reference:** See page 359 in section 7.5 of *Concrete Mathematics*
 by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik. See also [this paper](http://www.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Classes/Four_Proofs_of_Ballot_Theorem.pdf).